# excel vba insert row and change color

Tags: vba, excel, colors, format

I need to change the color of a row ( or cells A thru H in specific row), that has been inserted by the macro code below. The if statement that scans Col H, is where the color change needs to happen.

```
Sub SolidWorks()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Activate
Range("N1") = ActiveCell.Row

For lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If Cells(lrow, "B") = 0 Then
            Rows(lrow).EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next lrow

For lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(lrow, "H") <> Cells(lrow - IIf(lrow = 1, 0, 1), "H") Then
            Rows(lrow).EntireRow.Insert  '<---- insert green row, instead of just a blank row
'.Color = 5287936
'                With Selection.Interior
'                .Pattern = xlSolid
'                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
'                .Color = 5287936
'                .TintAndShade = 0
'                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
'                End With
    End If
Next lrow

For lrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(lrow, "G") <> Cells(lrow - IIf(lrow = 1, 0, 1), "G") Then
            Rows(lrow).EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next lrow

Range("A1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Go to the macro recorder and manually change the properties of a row. Then take that knowledge and insert the code as needed into your VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it there, you just need one line after 
`Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert`

and that is `Range("A" & lRow & ":H" & lRow).Interior.Color = 5287936`

Comment: I knew I must be close but its almost embarrassing I was that close. Thanks Scott